# How Push API works internally?

Tags: android, ios, browser, operating-system

I was wondering how the actual request from Server get routed to the Application if the browser is not running. Also, does the service workers maintain an active connection to the server so that it receives the push notification whenever the server publishes something?

Answer (score 0):

I think for every iOS device, Apple keeps a socket open between that device and the Apple Push Notification Service. Which essentially acts as a router for all notifications across all apps and all devices. So your server can send messages to APNS saying "yo, hit up this guy with this message", and APNS will use the socket it has open with every device to send the notification.

Also check out https://developer.apple.com/notifications/.
And https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server